# Update column in all tables inside schema with one query

Tags: mysql

is it possible to update multiple tables inside one schema with one query? The tables in question are named like `posting_0001`, `posting_0002`, etc. 
And they all have the column in question named `rating`. Now I want to use the `ceiling()` on the `rating`column but over ALL these `posting_xxx` tables within the schema.

So I would need something like ..

```
UPDATE ALL_TABLES_INSIDE_SCHEMA 
SET rating = ceiling(rating) 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'posting_%';
```

Is there a way to achieve this within mysql? Or do I have to write a script (python/php) on my computer to get it done..

Comment: Afaik it is not possible with single query. You can get all table names, which has this column, and then use Dynamic SQL

Comment: You can get all the table names from information_schema.tables and then build prepared statements (plural) for submission to dynamic sql. Not difficult but if you are comfortable with python/php just go with that.

Comment: crap, I already thought so. Thanks both of yall for confirming